# Scaling postgresSQL database when searching polygons against points?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, performance, clustering, development

I am using our single server -

- CentOS 6.6 x64
- 16 CPU
- 24 GB
- SSD
- (PostgreSQL) 9.4.1

as our GIS database processing engine. This is part of the PostGIS software package installed on the server.

I am currently using near realtime polygon data against U.S. Census information to compute statistics. It works well and performance is acceptable.

What I would like to do, is add the ability mark homes/businesses and when a future polygon intersects that location, notify someone.

I have a sense of how I might program the SQL to do this, but I am really concerned about the performance. I run this query every hour on the previous hour of polygons I have received.

They are small polygons typically, but if I accumulate thousands of point locations to monitor, my concern is how I deal with performance.

I saw that the latest release of postgresSQL 9.6, has some support for parallel processing. I don't know if that would help in anyway.  I have also briefly read about some ability for postgresSQL to work in a cluster relationship across multiple servers.

Does anyone have a recommended strategy for building this the "right way" so that I do not run into performance issues and can scale the application?

Comment: This question is at the razor's edge for being both *too broad* and *opinion-based*

Comment: Please take the [Tour], which explains how GIS SE is a question/answer database, and that "chit-chat", like thanks does not belong